# HTML Form Option (Yes or No) Then Dropdown Text Area

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is to have a text area that when I enter 'Yes' on the inbound and if I click on 'Yes' it will open a textarea at the bottom or at its left so that I could input what is the name of the inbound item. 
If answered 'No' then there should be no textarea shown (the default is no) 
After that I still want it to show when I click on the submit button 
Please take a look at my snippet so that you will have the idea.

Note: The default is 'No    '

```html
<html>
    <body>
         
        <form id="myForm">
        Name: <br><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" size="40"/><br/>
        Phone: <br><input type="text" name="Phone No" placeholder="Phone Number"/><br/>
       
       INBOUND: <br><select name="INBOUND" placeholder="INBOUND"><option>No<option>Yes</select><br/>

        <button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p>Result:</p>
        <p><textarea cols=40 rows=7 id="show" onClick='selectText(this);'></textarea></p>

            <script>
            function ShowText(){
                // find each input field inside the 'myForm' form:
                var inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll('input,select');
                // declare 'box' variable (textarea element):
                var box = document.getElementById('show');
                // clear the 'box':
                box.value = '';
                // loop through the input elements:
                for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
                    // append 'name' and 'value' to the 'box':
                    box.value += inputs[i].name + ': '+inputs[i].value+'\n';
                }
            }M
            function selectText(textField) 
              {
                textField.focus();
                textField.select();
              }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know, punctuation characters are not just for writing code.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about sorry but im new in this kind of field.

Comment: He's talking about writing your question in proper sentences, with periods at the end of each one, instead of writing a long run-on sentence.

Comment: So he's here just to brag about that instead of something else lmao.

Comment: SO is not just for your personal benefit, we're trying to create a knowledge base for the entire community. Questions that are hard to read are not as much benefit to everyone else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because I can't understand the question due to the lack of clarity and difficulty understanding.

Comment: @DavidThomas does this mean that you don't have any logic at all?

Comment: It means you couldn't be bothered to ask a coherent, understandable question; which means, in turn, I can't be bothered to try and answer it or allow it to remain open. If you [edit] your question to make it comprehensible then I am, however, quite likely to retract my close/hold vote.

Comment: @DavidThomas well someone just got the logic below :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete running example.

Hope this will helps you

```html
<html>
        <body>
         
        <form id="myForm">
        Name: <br><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" size="40"/><br/>
        Phone: <br><input type="text" name="Phone No" placeholder="Phone Number"/><br/>
       
       INBOUND: <br><select name="INBOUND" id="INBOUND" onchange="showTextArea()" placeholder="INBOUND"><option>No<option>Yes</select><br/>

        <button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p>Result:</p>
        <p><textarea cols=40 rows=7 id="show" onClick='selectText(this);'></textarea></p>
          
          <div id="location" style="display:none;"><p>Location:</p>
        <p><textarea cols=40 rows=7  onClick='selectText(this);'></textarea>
            </div>
            </p>
            
            <script>
            function ShowText(){
             
                // find each input field inside the 'myForm' form:
                var inputs = myForm.querySelectorAll('input,select');
                // declare 'box' variable (textarea element):
                var box = document.getElementById('show');
                // clear the 'box':
                box.value = '';
                // loop through the input elements:
                for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
                    // append 'name' and 'value' to the 'box':
                    box.value += inputs[i].name + ': '+inputs[i].value+'\n';
                }
            }M
            function selectText(textField) 
              {
                textField.focus();
                textField.select();
              }
              function showTextArea() 
              {
                var e = document.getElementById("INBOUND");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                
                if(strUser == 'Yes')
                  {
                    document.getElementById('location').style.display = "block";
                  }
                else
                  {
                    document.getElementById('location').style.display = "none";
                    }
                
                
              }
            </script>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        </body></html>
```

Comment: Why does it just show only when i click on yes i mean a different text/area for the yes option. Because if i just choose no it doesn't show the box when i click submit. I mean i want a different text area to input the location if i answered yes.

Comment: Hi, please check i modified as you requested. Please accept answers if you got the solution. Thanks

Comment: Allright awesome thats the idea but i just want a small box at the bottom of inbound if answered yes, and when i input the a text on that box it'll show too on the result when i click on submit is it possible?